# How can I access a functional components state outside the component? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

For example, if I have the functional component Dropdown that receives data from an api to populate a dropdown selection, and uses the following hook to update the state of the value selected

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
```

How might I then access/read the value (in this case an array of numbers) outside of the Dropdown component?

For better context I will include firstly where the Dropdown component is used:

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropdown from '../Components/Dropdown.js'
import GraphTypeDropdown from '../Components/GraphTypeDropdown.js'

function CreateGraph() {

    //function receiving and returning data (array of data points and their heading) from api

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch('/dropdowndata');
        const receivedData = await response.json();
        return receivedData;
    }

    //assigning data to myData variable

    const myData = getData();

    //myData is passed to Dropdown components as a prop to allow selection of data columns
    //GraphTypeDropdown allows selection of the graph "type"

    return (
        <div>
            <Dropdown myData={myData} />
            <Dropdown myData={myData} />
            <Dropdown myData={myData} />
            <Dropdown myData={myData} />
            <Dropdown myData={myData} />
            <GraphTypeDropdown />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateGraph;
```

And also the full code of the dropdown functional component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dropdown.css';

function Dropdown(props) {
    const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState();

    //maps the prop myData to be the label and value of the dropdown list

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function getColumns() {
            props.myData.then(function(result) {
                setColumns(result.map(({ heading, values }) => ({ label: heading, value: values })));
            });
        }
        getColumns();
    }, [props.myData]);

    //creates a dropdown where value (array of data points) can be selected with label (column headings)
    //value selected is then saved in the state of the dropdown

    return (
        <select className='DropDown'
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        >
            {columns.map(({ label, heading, value }) => (
                <option className='DropDown'
                    key={heading}
                    value={value}
                >
                    {label}
                 </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

How will I be able to use/access the arrays assigned to value in the five Dropdown components?

Comment: For your specific case (`<Dropdown />`-components are immediate children of `<CreateGraph />`-component, where the data should be consumed), I would recommend to leverage the [Lift Stat Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) technique

Comment: And, by the way, if you expect to get suggestions in form of viable pieces of code, relevant to your existing codebase, I would recommend to set up the live sandbox (e.g. at stackblitz.com or codesandbox.io)

Comment: You'll need to initiate the state of the drop downs on your `CreateGraph` and pass the `value` and `setValue` functions to them as props. You can do 5 `useState` functions or use an object/array and have each bound to a key or index.

Comment: There seems to multiple things that are wrong with the implementation and the way both components are connected.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question *"access the value outside of the component?"* would be:
*You generally **can not** access the state of a functional component from outside that component*.

What you can do is:

- pass props "down" (to children)
- props can be callback functions, this way you could pass state "up"
- use a framework with global state, like [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux).

Now it depends a lot on your use case what the best solution is.

An example for passing the state "up" would be:

```
function Dropdown(props) {
    // ...
    React.useEffect(() => {
        props.onLoaded( columns );
    }, [ columns ]);
    // ...
}

function CreateGraph() {
    // ...
    <Dropdown
        myData={ myData }
        onLoaded={
            (columns) => {
                console.log('columns:', columns);
            }
        }
    />
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and helpful comment, as you can probably tell I am new to React/Javascript and coding in general so this answer has made things as clear as possible. I will look more into lifting state up and see if I'm able to implement this in such a way to achieve my outcome.